# Deploying Nodejs app with Adminjs dashboard on google cloud read only file system error

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, admin-bro, adminjs

I have been trying to upload my Nodejs app to google cloud app engine and I am using Adminjs inside. In my root folder, I have .adminjs folder and .entry.js file nested inside. Google console logs explorer gives [Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open '.adminjs/.entry.js']. Please help.

edited

this is my AdminJs code:

```
const admin = new AdminJS({
    databases: [],
    rootPath: path.join(__dirname,'/tmp'),
    resources:[UsersResources, GuestResources, SalesResources, FinancesResources, TicketsResources, DestinationsResources, JadrolinijaTokenResources],
   /* components:{
        edit: Components.MyDashboard
    },*/
    dashboard:{
        component: AdminJS.bundle(path.join(process.cwd(), './components/dashboard'))

    }
   //componentLoader,


})
```

Answer (score 0):

This [github issue](https://github.com/SoftwareBrothers/adminjs/issues/751) discusses this problem. App Engine's standard environment does allow you to write files to the `/tmp` directory, and you can make AdminJS use `/tmp/.adminjs` by specifying the environment variable `ADMIN_JS_TMP_DIR`. So in your `app.yaml`, have this:

```yaml
env_variables:
  ADMIN_JS_TMP_DIR: /tmp/.adminjs
```